# How to port FreeRTOS to a core without an interrupt controller

Tags: arm, interrupt, freertos

I am working on a project which involves porting FreeRTOS to a custom SoC. This SoC features a Cortex R5 core together with an FPGA fabric. Unfortunately, the R5 core comes without any interrupt controller (neither GIC nor VIC).

Is there anything I can do here? (Other than writing my own interrupt controller).

Comment: I have done a lot of work on Cortex-R systems. Seems strange that you do not have any type of interrupt controller. Does not seem very useful. Do you have a timer which can generate a system tick? I think as long as you have this you can do something. Do you have any other external interrupts (I assume they would all come in on the processor IRQ and determined by software?)

Comment: I wrote an APB timer and now it is connected to the nIRQm port of the core. Interrupt being handled every x milliseconds, etc, works fine. The idea for now is that I could use the main tick to check whether any other peripheral has raised an "interrupt". Is this what you thought too?

Comment: I don't think that would work very well as you would only find out about other interrupts every tick period. I think you would need to OR all the interrupts into the the nIRQm port and use software to determine the source. Can you not write a simple interrupt controller in the FGPA (don't ask me how). The SoC designer should have really included an ARM VIC.

Comment: Oh of course I can do that. The problem I have is that the CR5 port of FreeRTOS expects some GIC registers (like ICCIAR etc.) and right now every time it tries to acces one of those I'm getting a data abort exception. I want to have a *minimal* working example for now, and I'm stuck a little bit.

Comment: I can't think of a simple solution. I cannot really think why you would not put an ARM VIC/GIC with the R5. It is pretty much essential unless you have a very specific scenario that does not need one.